# How to implement onClicklistener in listview inside fragment to move to next fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

Below is my code, I'm using to populate my fragment with listview that contains Text and Images.
I would like to know, How to move to next fragment when item is clicked from listview items. 
For example if first Item is clicked will open Fragment A and if second Item is clicked will open Fragment B.

I'm using below as solution but it isn't working.
[image]

Any help will be highly appreicated.

```css
package com.nepalpolice.cdp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by Sagar on 2017/09/23.
 */


public class club extends Fragment  {
    // Array of strings storing country names
    String[] countries = new String[]{
            "India",
            "Pakistan",
            "Sri Lanka",
            "China",
            "Bangladesh",
            "Nepal",
            "Afghanistan",
            "North Korea",
            "South Korea",
            "Japan"
    };

    // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
    int[] flags = new int[]{
            R.drawable.eka,
            R.drawable.kat,
            R.drawable.rat,
            R.drawable.set,
            R.drawable.ann,
            R.drawable.kar,
            R.drawable.suk,
            R.drawable.sap,
            R.drawable.him,
            R.drawable.gor
    };

    // Array of strings to store currencies
    String[] currency = new String[]{
            "Indian Rupee",
            "Pakistani Rupee",
            "Sri Lankan Rupee",
            "Renminbi",
            "Bangladeshi Taka",
            "Nepalese Rupee",
            "Afghani",
            "North Korean Won",
            "South Korean Won",
            "Japanese Yen"
    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_club, container, false);
// Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
        List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hm.put("txt", "Country : " + countries[i]);
            hm.put("cur", "Currency : " + currency[i]);
            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]));
            aList.add(hm);
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = {"flag", "txt", "cur"};

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = {R.id.flag, R.id.txt, R.id.cur};

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);
        // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Setting the adapter to the listView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
        return view;
    }

// Setting the adapter to the listView


    // Item Click Listener for the listview
    OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View container, int position, long id) {
            // Getting the Container Layout of the ListView
            if(position == 1/*or any other position*/){
                Fragment fragment = new notices();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
            else if(position == 2){


            } // etc...
        }
    };
}
```

I tried to add public class club extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener  but it throws me error with class must be declared abstract..

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @WaqasBukhary no it is not...you must first go through the whole question before you decide.

Comment: It isn't working is not helpful.  What's the error? please try to reduce the code to a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {
      //Your click code here. 
    }
});
```

OR

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
```

as you already have defined *itemClickListener* in your class.

Comment: could you explain bit more , as you solution is not working. How do I implement your solution in above code.

Comment: I really don't know how to add your solution inside above code.....so I have not tried yet...could you please add your solution to above code and post the whole code....I'm new to android..so I'm learning new things and I tried to do myself but all I was left questions only.

Comment: just add this line listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener); after listView.setAdapter(adapter);